# Write a program that asks the user for a string and then prints the string in upper case

Tags: python

I am learning programming language by my own from (CEMC Python from scratch) and this is my first programming language. I spend more than 3 hour to solve this PROBLEM. Please help to solve this so I can get to know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: `print(input().upper())`

Comment: You haven't shown us what you are struggling with. Please edit the question and post your code, explain where you are having trouble (exceptions, wrong output, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

```
# python 2.x
>>>text = raw_input()
# python 3.x
>>>text = input()
>>>print(text.upper())
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# script.py

string = input("write a string ")

print(string.upper())
```

I tested it on python and it works :)